# Can't add nuget package with dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I am trying to install the `xunit` NuGet package using the dotnet core CLI with this command:

```
dotnet add package xunit -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

From within the class library folder. However, I see this when executing that line:

```
  Writing C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp7238.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'xunit' into project 'C:\git\Testing\TestLib\TestLib.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\git\Testing\TestLib\TestLib.csproj...
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit/index.json
error: Unable to load the service index for source https://<mysourcecontrol>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/libs/nuget/v3/index.json.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

AFAIK this is telling me that the nuget utility on my machine cannot find relevant info about our on-prem NuGet source. What I don't understand is why that is even a question - I am specifying the source to use (which is the regular nuget.org path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `%appdata%\nuget\nuget.config` had entries which the NuGet tool did not like. I removed them and retried and the installs worked.